# HX711 arduino Scale offset drift

Tags: arduino-nano

I am working around with HX711 ADC and a 5kg load cell, it seems the HX711 library is some sort of mystery no one wants to reveal!
Please someone explain me, I promise to keep the secret ;)

Anyone here can suggest a coding trick to compensate drifting in the reading values?
Actually the slope is ok, but the offset is not stable, also I don't know the difference between these two:

```
scale.set_offset();
scale.get_offset();
```

How these two actually do the job and shall I use them in the `void loop()` function?
Also that would be really helpful to suggest me a code for averaging readings beside what the library pre-used, like `scale.get_units()`

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried auto zero, that works very well if the circuit is stable.

Comment: @Gil can you please explain more, no I don't know what is auto zero

Comment: Zero the reading when there is no load on the scale. this goes into great detail: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/demystifying-auto-zero-amplifiers-part-1.html I do not know your system but a guess would be a low reading would be no load, save that and use it when you get a quick increase in weight use that as your correction factor.

Comment: @Gil thanks man you helped a lot

Comment: You are welcome!